# Splitting python codebase with single package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I have some python code that consists of server, client, and common code that I'm trying to split into separate project sharing a package namespace. I've seen a few similar questions, but they seem to refer to packages that are separate but have a name collision.

I'm trying to make a simple example work with

```
a
├── pkg
│   ├── a.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── setup.py
b
├── pkg
│   ├── b.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

**a/setup.py**

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='pkg_a',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pkga=pkg.a:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

**a.py**

```
def main():
    print('Module A')
```

Note that `b/setup.py` and `b.py` are the same with references to `a` changed to `b`.

If I do a `pip install .` in each of these directories, the commands `pka` and `pkgb` both work, but an `import pkg.a` or `import pkg.b` only works with the last one installed. Both `a.py` and `b.py`, along with a single empty `__init__.py` are in `site-packages/pkg`.

Is there any way to make this setup work? Is it be a bad idea to try to share a package name across packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `pkg` a *namespace package*:

- [explicit namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).
- [setuptools' namespace packages](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages).

Though the first method based on `pkgutil` is officially recommended, the second method based on `setuptools` & `pkg_resources` is widely used (for historical reasons), and is needed if you inject into the existing legacy namespaces of other libraries.

For the setuptools way, put this line into `pkg/__init__.py` in both libraries:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Declare them in both `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    namespace_packages=['pkg']
)
```

Done.